# Jsoup behaves different from my test PC and the server

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm testing a web crawler with JSoup. The issue comes when I test the crawler on a regular PC, and works as expected, then I export this web crawler as a jar to work in a server in a cron job. This where the things go wrong.

The code is the same, no changes. The data I'm trying to extract is different comments from the users of how they rate a service, the problem is that the web crawler behaves differently when it's executed in the server, for example: the comments are duplicated, something that doesn't happened when I'm testing the program locally.

Also the web crawler differentiates what language the comments are written (I take that info from the URL, `.de` for German, `.es` for Spanish, etc). This info get mixed for example, a comment in Spanish is classified as Portuguese one.

Again I repeat the logic behind the crawler is correct, I tested many times with different input.

**What could be the problem behind these issues?**

Additional notes:

- No exceptions/crashes.
- I'm using jsoup 1.9.2.
- This is how I get the data from the website:

  `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent(FakeAgentBooking.getAgent()).timeout(60 * 4000).get();`
- I already tried to use a proxy just in case the server was banned.

  System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", "PROXY");
      System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", "PORT");
      System.getProperties().put("https.proxyUser", "USER");
      System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPassword", "PASSWORD");

This is the code of the cron job:

```
@Crawler(name = "Booking comments", nameType = "BOOKING_COMMENTS", sentimetal = true, cron = "${cron.booking.comments}")
public class BookingCommentsJob extends MotherCrawler {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookingCommentsJob.class);

    @Value("${full.booking.comments}")
    private String full;

    @Autowired
    private ComentariosCDMXRepository comentariosCDMXRepository;

    @Override
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setInfo(this.getClass().getAnnotation(Crawler.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void exec(int num) {
        // <DEBUG>
        String startTime = time.format(new Date());
        // </DEBUG>

        Set<CrawQuery> li = queryManager.getMeQueries(type, num, threadnum);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        for (CrawQuery s : li) {
            String query = s.getQuery().get("query");
            try {
                                //the crawling begins here-->
                String result = BookingComentarios.crawlBookingComentarios(query, Boolean.parseBoolean(full));
                //get the result from json to a standarized class
                ComentarioCDMX[] myComments = gson.fromJson(result, ComentarioCDMX[].class);
                for (ComentarioCDMX myComment : myComments) {
                    //evaluates if the comment is positive, neutral or negative.
                    Integer sentiment = sentimentAnalysis.classifyVector(myComment.getComment());
                    myComment.setSentiment(sentiment);
                    myComment.setQuery(query);
                    /* <Analisis de sentimiento /> */
                    comentariosCDMXRepository.save(myComment);
                }
                s.setStatus(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(query, e);
                s.setStatus(false);
                mailSend.add(e);
            } finally {
                s.setLastUse(new Date());
                //Saves data to Solr
                crawQueryDao.save(s);
            }
        }
        update();

        // <DEBUG>
        String endTime = time.format(new Date());
        logger.info(name + " " + num + " > Inicio: " + startTime + ", Fin: " + endTime);
        // </DEBUG>
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.booking.comments}")
    public void curro0() throws InterruptedException {
        exec(0);
    }
}
```

and this is when the code should be executed:

```
cron.booking.comments=00 30 02 * * *
```

**Additional notes:**
The test PC OS is Windows 7 and the server OS is linux Debian 3.16.7. and tghe java version in the test PC is 1.7  oracle JDK and on the server is 1.8.0 JRE.

Comment: Could multiple cron jobs running? Without seeing your code, I could not comment on why it mixed up the languages.

Comment: yes, but only one crawler per website

Comment: @MinhKieu added code to the question

Comment: Does the server and desktop have the same OS? The same Java (Oracle, OpenJDK, ...)? The same Java version? Could you please debug your remote code and confirm that jsoup is returning some items wrong or duplicate?

Comment: @Ph3n1x Now that you mention that, maybe the version of java in the server could be different gonna check that, test PC OS is Windows and the server OS is linux (not sure what version gonna check that too)

Comment: @Ph3n1x Added those details to the question

Comment: Both oracle? Could you try to add some logging `LOG.info(result);` before you parse with Gson. Then please check if the results on the server and desktop are different.

Comment: @Ph3n1x i did that, that's when i realized that the results are duped and with the wrong info, note that this is _before_ parsing with Gson

Comment: @B.J.A.A. Did you manage with this problem? Have the same.

Comment: @MaxGabderakhmanov no, sorry i don't, i have been moved to another project for the moment. I think it might it has relation with the robots.txt but not sure.